# Convert the DateTime string to string

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core, json.net

I have a JToken defaultValuesToken which has many JProperty properties in C# code. One property of type Date. I am running a foreach loop and converting the property value to a string using the `ToString` method. Problem with this code is that the `ToString()` method provides the converted string different different date format as per the my windows system regional format. the given date is 2023-01-30T15:30:59.000753Z. But it gives value "1/30/2023 3:30:59 PM" when regional format is English (United States) and it gives value "30/01/2023 15:30:59" when the regional format is English (Germany).

Below is my code.

```
foreach (JProperty defaultValueToken in defaultValuesToken)
{
    var value = defaultValueToken.Value.ToString();
}
```

I am able to fix the issue using the below code by adding a check for type Date, But I need to do this at **many** places, so If there a better way to solve this problem? Is there a global setting so that I need to make the change only in **one** place and it should work throughout the application?

```
foreach (JProperty defaultValueToken in defaultValuesToken)
{
    if (defaultValueToken.Value.Type == JTokenType.Date)
    {
        var value = defaultValueToken.Value.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None));
    }
    else
    {
        var value = defaultValueToken.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: `ToString(CutltureInfo.InvariantCutlure);` or `ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` or any desired format | https://dotnetfiddle.net/zaoGCu

Comment: I want to do this at many places, so Is there any global setting to do this in one place only?

Comment: Why are you converting the dataTime yourself anyway json.net supports datetime natively, so instead of converting to string just pass it a datetime and let the library handle it

Comment: `ToString(CutltureInfo.InvariantCutlure)` gives error cannot convert from 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting'

Comment: @RandRandom it is the legacy code and I want to make the minimal changes here. value is being used as string at other places

Comment: after googling a bit I believe this should be possible `defaultValueToken.Value.Value<DateTime>();` can you verify?

Comment: @RandRandom I want to get the string not DateTime

Comment: but... once you have an actually `DateTime` object you can call `ToString` as I showed initially

Comment: @RandRandom still has the same behaviour. But again I don't want to change in many places. Is there a global setting/configuration to achieve this?

Comment: Some ideas: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bg2Gzo

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the *original* string, or the date/time in a particular format? A [mcve] would make it much clearer. (If you want the original string, just disable Json.NET's automatically date parsing...)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can set a global date format for serialization and deserialization:

```
public class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private const string DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ";

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTime) || objectType == typeof(DateTime?);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(reader.Value.ToString(), DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var result))
        {
            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is DateTime dateTime)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(dateTime.ToString(DateFormat));
        }
    }
}
```

Register the DateTimeConverter with JsonConvert

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new DateTimeConverter() }
};
```

Comment: I already tried this. But this is also making no difference

Comment: updated the post. try this

Comment: This is also not working

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cultures of the current thread like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; // for the UI
```

Use the culture you need from the CultureInfo enum.

Comment: That might be a dangerous suggestion if the thread also does other things besides this conversion from json.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common for types like DateTime to have both ToString and Parse-methods that take a `IFormatProvider` that you can assign a culture to. Note that a DateTime values them selves are in no way culture dependent, only the string representation. But datetimes can be implicitly converted to strings when displayed in a UI, and then the system culture will be used.

Json should always use the invariant culture. Normally your json parser should take care of this for you. If you are manually writing values to a json file you should make sure to always use `.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. This should be the case for all values that are converted to strings, not just datetime.

If you have some invalid json with incorrect formatted values, there is a [JsonSerializer.Culture](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Culture.htm) property you could set. Or just set the correct culture when parsing the value.

I would not recommend changing the global CurrentCulture in an UI program just for reading/writing json, since that affects formatting across the entire program, and this will very likely impact usability.

Answer (score 0):

To convert DateTime to string

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
string dateTimeString = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
```

In this example, we are using the `ToString` method with the format string `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"`, which represents the date and time in the ISO 8601 format. The `T` specifier is used to separate the date and time components, and the `Z` specifier indicates that the time is in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).